# Fetch MongoDb Documents whose timestamp is today

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongodb model whose creation date is stored in milliseconds(epoch time). I want to fetch only documents whose milliseconds matches today.

So, here is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
let query = {"pick_up_time":12262672627271}; // I want this to translate to pick_up_time is today
```

Is it possible to apply a transformation function to this?

I have this function to check if requested date is today

```
function isToday(someDate) {
    const today = new Date()
    return someDate.getDate() == today.getDate() &&
        someDate.getMonth() == today.getMonth() &&
        someDate.getFullYear() == today.getFullYear()
}
```

So, that my query will now be

```
let query = {"pick_up_time":isToday(12262672627271)};
```

How can something like this be achieved with mongodb?

Comment: I would suggest [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/) library: `moment(12262672627271).isSame(moment(), 'day')`

Answer (score 0):

I think this function can help you to create dynamic queries for each day

```js
const getTimeQuery = () => {
    const now = new Date();
    const year = now.getFullYear();
    const month = now.getMonth();
    const day = now.getDate();

    const startDate = new Date(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0).getTime();
    const endDate = new Date(year, month, day, 24, 0, 0).getTime();


    const query = {
        "pick_up_time": { $gte: startDate, $lte: endDate }
    }

    return query
}



console.log(getTimeQuery());
```